# React state change not showing changes when going back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that lists books on a users shelf and then on a subsequent search page.
The user goes to the search page, finds a title and selects a shelf for the title to be shelved on. When they go back to the home page this title should then show on the correct shelf.

The functionality works in that the changes are made to the objects, but when I click on the home button or back button in the browser the changes do not show until I have refreshed the browser.

What do I need to do to ensure this change is shown when the user browses to the home page?

I've put the bulk of the code into [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/richardcurteis/myreads-udacity)

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ListBooks from './ListBooks'
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks'
import * as BooksAPI from './utils/BooksAPI'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class BooksApp extends Component {

  state = {
    books: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll()
    .then((books) => {
      this.setState(() => ({
        books
      }))
    })
  }

  updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
    const bookFromState = this.state.books.find(b => b.id === book.id);
    if (bookFromState) {
      // update existing
      bookFromState.shelf = shelf;
      this.setState(currentState => ({
        books: currentState.books
      }));
    } else {
      // add new one
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        books: prevState.books
      }));
    }
    BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
          <ListBooks
          books={this.state.books}
          onUpdateShelf={this.updateShelf}
          />
        )} />
        <Route exact path='/search' render={() => (
          <SearchBooks
          books={this.state.books}
          onUpdateShelf={this.updateShelf}
          />
        )} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default BooksApp
```

Comment: your sandbox is not working

Comment: It does, just click the yellow tab in the browser window of the sandbox. Not sure why that error shows up but it's only in the sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked your code. You had problem updating your state actually. The `books` wasn't changing after you selected a book from within the search screen. Here's the code from your App.js:

```
updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
  console.log(book, shelf)
  const bookFromState = this.state.books.find(b => b.id === book.id);
  if (bookFromState) {
    // update existing
    bookFromState.shelf = shelf;
    this.setState(currentState => ({
      books: currentState.books
    }));
  } else {
    // add new one
    // the following lines of yours were different
      book.shelf = shelf;
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        books: prevState.books.concat(book)
    }));
  }
  BooksAPI.update(book, shelf);
};
```

So you merely had `books: prevState.books` instead of actually concatenating the book to the prev state. And just before that the shelf of book has to be changed to the one you pass.
PS: I might have left some `console.log` statements. Hope that is not a problem and you will clean the mess.

Comment: Awesome! Cheers mate, that was spot on